# What does "Add to Queue" mean in "Play Music"?

Tags: google-play-store, music-player

What does "Add to Queue" mean in "Play Music"?  I've seen an answer elsewhere which said "it adds to the current play list."  That answer makes no sense.  What "current play list?"  There is no such concept in the application.

For example, I'll start the application and no music is playing yet.  I'll go to my playlists and pick one.  Again, no music is playing yet.  Then I can pick "add to queue."  Nothing happens.  I have no idea what that just did.

I then select a song to start playing, and I'm on my way.  I still have no idea what the "add to queue" accomplished.

I'm using the Samsung S4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Queue is the "Currently Playing Playlist"

You have Playlist A with Song 1,2,3 and 4.

If you start listening to Playlist A, The Currently Playing Playlist will consist of Song 1,2,3,4.

If you see Song 1337 , then "add to queue" while listening to Song 2, the Currently Playing Playlist will consist of Song 2,1337,3,4.

If the next day, you start Playlist A from the beginning, it will still only hold Song 1,2,3,4.

Comment: They might have changed the behavior and the queued Song might now play after all objects in the current playlist ( 2,3,4,1337) or if you add song 1338 it might put it after the previously queued song (2,1337,1338,3,4). I cant tell for sure, but the principle is still the same.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to queue means there should be something playing first before the queue is created. Try playing one song then add another music to the queue. Don't pick another song, just wait for the current song to finish. The next song will be the song you placed in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You add songs one after the other.

So the last song you have added will play at the end.

Comment: The accepted answer indicates that the added song will play next, rather than at the end.  Do you see it behaving differently?

Comment: If a song is playing and u added a song to the queue and u want to add another it will play after both songs and not after the first one.